# Matplotlib: 16 subplots in 16 grid: list Index out of range

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to plot 16 subplots with the code below but I'm getting a `IndexError: list index out of range` error even though my while condition has the same length...why is that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_new = [5436, 7]
y_new = [[0.040028619784490037, 0.064413738530207612, 0.062815762675466444, 0.073433012173153914, 0.032932640559388944, 0.093132462472780564, 0.86465850284943391, 1.6305790768438158, 2.9282502771409802, 2.2143984435689292, 3.763690626719586, 3.7678535429124818, 3.1207650603328103, 2.661000804740647, 2.323640314964067, 2.3603270205788753], [0.028737592073923207, 0.044262388955502406, 0.046552654094977768, 0.056216098251445794, 0.032034316764190607, 0.07977527592601974, 0.8403112875093226, 1.5060638978019212, 2.5880236300872195, 2.1269536152167832, 3.4154460490965977, 3.4493404237456957, 2.9860435093537485, 2.618519230197268, 2.3377423748500568, 2.4191266598989216]]

# Sorting Data
idx = np.argsort(np.array(x_new))
y_new = np.array(y_new)[idx]
x_new = np.array(x_new)[idx]    

fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)

i=1
j=0
subplotnr = range(1,17,1)

while j <= 17:
    print "i, j: ", i, j
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4, 4, subplotnr[i])

    # Data handling
    y_new_plot = []
    for ch in range(len(x_new)):
        y_new_plot.append(y_new[ch][j])
    print y_new_plot

    # Plotting Subplots
    ax.plot(x_new, y_new_plot)
    i=i+1
    j=j+1
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code,

- `y_new = [[ 0.02873759  0.04426239  0.04655265  ...` won't work on python
- `j <= range(0,16,1)` does not make sense
- `plt.show()` inside the loop will render the progress at every step

Here is a simpler version, you can adapt to your needs

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def subplot(ax, i, j):

    # plot the (i, j)-subplot here
    x = [1, 2]
    y = [3, 4]

    ax.plot(x, y)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(12)
fig.set_figwidth(12)

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):

        if i == 0 and j == 3: continue

        ax = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (i, j))


        subplot(ax, i, j)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To answer OP's new questions

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_new = [5436, 7]
y_new = [[0.040028619784490037, 0.064413738530207612, 0.062815762675466444, 0.073433012173153914, 0.032932640559388944, 0.093132462472780564, 0.86465850284943391, 1.6305790768438158, 2.9282502771409802, 2.2143984435689292, 3.763690626719586, 3.7678535429124818, 3.1207650603328103, 2.661000804740647, 2.323640314964067, 2.3603270205788753], [0.028737592073923207, 0.044262388955502406, 0.046552654094977768, 0.056216098251445794, 0.032034316764190607, 0.07977527592601974, 0.8403112875093226, 1.5060638978019212, 2.5880236300872195, 2.1269536152167832, 3.4154460490965977, 3.4493404237456957, 2.9860435093537485, 2.618519230197268, 2.3377423748500568, 2.4191266598989216]]

# Sorting Data
idx = np.argsort(np.array(x_new))
y_new = np.array(y_new)[idx]
x_new = np.array(x_new)[idx]    

fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)

i=1
j=0
subplotnr = range(0, 17,1)

while j <= 15:
    #print("i, j: ", i, j)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4, 4, subplotnr[i])

    y_new_plot = []
    for ch in range(len(x_new)):
        y_new_plot.append(y_new[ch][j])
    #print(y_new_plot)

    ax.plot(x_new, y_new_plot)
    i=i+1
    j=j+1
plt.show()
```

Comment: Those were mistakes in order to make it simpler since it's only an extract from a code sorry about that. I'll have a look if I can integrate your answer into my code

Comment: I made some changes to the code above. if you run it you'll get the same error message now

Comment: @Shaun Change to `while j <= 14`

Comment: No wait...it's not including the last entriy of the y_new list! In fact there should be 16 plots not 15. But why isn't it reading the last entries? it should be `while j<=17:`

Comment: @Shaun Your post starts with **I'm trying to plot 15 subplots with the code below ...** Do you want 15 subplots? or 16?

Comment: 16. It's all linked within the original code but printing the `len()` of that while condition showed that there should be 16 subplots (hence the length of y_new[0])

Comment: Yep that's it thank you very much. I thought subplot indices start at 1 instead of 0.